# Segmentation fault при попытке создать поток при статической линковке libstdc++

Tags: c++, cmake, сборка, c++17, линковка

Возникла необходимость статически слинковать все библиотеки при сборке бинарника. После добавления в cmake скрипт строки `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")` или `add_link_options(-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static)` любая попытка создать объект std::thread вызывает *Segmentation fault*.

ОС: Ubuntu 20.04,
Cmake v 3.19,
GCC 9.3.

Для воспроизведения проблемы написал небольшой проект.

Cmake скрипт:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(thread_test LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package (Threads)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
add_executable(thread_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

С++ код:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::thread;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    thread th([]() -> void {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        cout << "Some text." << endl;
    });
    th.join();
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если закомментировать строку `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")` то всё начинает работать как надо.

**upd:** Попробовал собрать этот с++ код руками. Всё тоже самое. `g++ -static -pthread -std=c++17 -o thread_test main.cpp`. После запуска *Segmentation fault*. Т.е. у g++ вообще не получается слинковать потоки статически. Вопрос, что делать, остаётся открытым.

Comment: а если статически прилинковать pthread?

Comment: @Bogdan разве проблемная строка не заставляет линковать статически всё что есть? Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример cmake скрипта где статически линкуется pthread? т.е. что мне необходимо добавить в свой скрипт?

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал попробовать провернуть эту же историю на g++ без cmake и, таким образом, убедиться, что проблема на уровне сборки программы, а не на уровне cmake. Далее, если проблема повторится, то копать в сторону правильной статической линковки, например, глянуть, что покажет `ldd`. Или глянуть что-то вроде [этого](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590) (внизу есть пример про pthread). Возможно стоит еще раз взвесить все "за" и "против" статической линковки.

Comment: @Bogdan Спасибо за помощь. 

*'Возможно стоит еще раз взвесить все "за" и "против" статической линковки.'* - мне надо запустить приложение на десятке старых arm машинах с очень старым тулчейном и вообще без библиотек, которые используются в проекте. Устанавливать что-то туда мне никто не даст, можно только заменить бинарник. Поэтому выбор у меня не большой.

Comment: попробовал этот же пример, но переписал его на си + pthread. работает и не падает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порылся у себя по исходникам и нашел. Потом нашел и на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116327/when-g-static-link-pthread-cause-segmentation-fault-why).

Штука в том, что нужно подлинковать ещё и библиотеку rt. В консоли получается где то так

```
g++ main.cpp -static -lrt -pthread -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

работает и для gcc, и для clang

Но вот как это сделать в cmake - не знаю.

Comment: я подключал rt в cmake, там очень просто. Как только окажусь у компа, сразу-же попробую. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: да я тоже подключал, но падало все равно

Comment: с этим примером всё заработало, в понедельник попробую собрать проект. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: разберетесь, как в cmake вставить это добро - пишите, мне самому интересно